# python db insert

Tags: python

I am in facing a performance problem in my code.I am making db connection a making a select query  and then inserting in a table.Around 500 rows in one select query ids populated .Before inserting i am running select query around 8-9 times first and then inserting then all using cursor.executemany.But it is taking 2 miuntes to insert which is not qood .Any idea

```
def insert1(id,state,cursor):

   cursor.execute("select * from qwert where asd_id =%s",[id])

   if sometcondition:

        adding.append(rd[i])

cursor.executemany(indata, adding)
```

where rd[i] is a aray for records making and indata is a insert statement

```
#prog start here


cursor.execute("select * from assd")



for rows in cursor.fetchall()

if rows[1]=='aq':


  insert1(row[1],row[2],cursor)

if rows[1]=='qw':

  insert2(row[1],row[2],cursor)
```

Comment: Please give us some code to look at.

Comment: Can you post some example code? It's hard to suggest improvements without it.

Comment: We can't even know what database engine you're using, what module you're using, or identify where the bottleneck might remotely be. Plus my eyes are bleeding from the formatting of your post.

Comment: Maybe you can also tag this question with 'sqlalchemy' (which I assume it's what you are using)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why you're doing this.

It seems that you want to insert a subset of rows from "assd" into one table, and another subset into another table?

Why not just do it with two SQL statements, structured like this:

```
insert into tab1 select * from assd where asd_id = 42 and cond1 = 'set';
insert into tab2 select * from assd where asd_id = 42 and cond2 = 'set';
```

That'd dramatically reduce your number of roundtrips to the database and your client-server traffic. It'd also be an order of magnitude faster.

Of course, I'd also strongly recommend that you specify your column names in both the insert and select parts of the code.

Comment: i have to check some conditions before inserting and in my select query i ma fectching data from 3 tables with some condition.

I m using psycopg2 for db connection and using postgressql database

Comment: The answer still stands - for best performance you should try to move your logic to your SQL. You could use unions to join the result sets of the three source tables (given that the columns are the same types). The idea is that, say, six queries to insert 60k rows will always be faster than 60006 queries with their associated round trips.

Comment: i m using regex in my logic and i think regex cannot be used in db scripts.Since all my things are in python so i want some uniformity.

Comment: As requested by others, what database are you using? Regex may be supported by your database.